# Perl freezes until ALL system() commands are done

Tags: perl, command, system, freeze, tk-toolkit

Here is an example of a code in Perl with TK:

```
my $btn_start = $mw->Button(-image => $img_start, -command => \&start)->pack;
MainLoop;


sub start{
my $topWin = $mw -> Toplevel;
my $entry = $topWin->Label(-textvariable=>\my $process)->pack();
$process="start 1st";
system("long_command.exe");
$process.="\nstart 2nd";
system("another_command.exe");
.
.
.
$process.="\nstart nth";
system("ncommand.exe");
}
```

The problem is when I press on the button, the toplevel window opens only after the system() commands finish the run (why do they start before anything else??), moreover $btn_start is still "active" during the whole process.
I'm trying to achieve a status update after each system() command.

Can you please advise?

Thank you in advance,
Mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you run the system() command, add an

```
$mw->update()
```

statement. What happens is that the main loop updates the windows every now and then; in your case, before the next scheduled update happens (which can only happen when start() returns to the main loop), system() is called and until it returns, nothing else will be executed -- because everything runs in the same process.

If you want to do the things properly, though, you should fork your process. Otherwise your application will not be reactive during the time that the command is executed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the user interface (buttons, labels, etc..) and the tasks they run (`system`) are both being run by the same process and in the same thread.  This is the naive way of writing a GUI program.

To get the effect you're looking for -- an active user interface while something else is happening in the background -- you'll need to investigate how to run them concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

[Note:  I don't have access to a running Tk, so the following is surmise based on first principles and documentation.  You have been warned.]

Tk is not getting control back in order to update the UI.  What is happening is that you've created the new `TopLevel`, but not given control back to `MainLoop` so as to allow it to be drawn.  Eventually, `start` returns, which gives control back to `MainLoop`, which performs all the pending updates at once.

If you want the UI to update while you're in the middle of a sub, you have to call `update` on the outermost interesting `Widget` periodically so as to hand control back to `MainLoop` for a spell.  In your case, that looks to be

```
$mw->update();
```

See also `update` on [perldoc Tk::Widget](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.030/pod/Widget.pod).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `system` stops *everything* (in the same thread) while it waits for the subprocess to complete. This includes stopping the serving of the GUI event queue, which is used to drive all sorts of things (including redraws).
Consider using the [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm) module to run the subprocesses asynchronously (with a regular timer to determine whether one task has finished and the next should start, assuming that only doing one at a time is important to your code).

Comment: I tried the Proc::Background, but unfortunately it freezes everything as well: my $proc=Proc::Background->new("x264.exe --someParameters someValues"); $proc->wait;    Am I doing something wrong?